# Шаблон классов и методы, определенные снаружи класса

Tags: c++

```css
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>

class Test
{
private:
    T value;
public:
    Test();
    Test(T valueOfUser);
    T getValue();
    T setValue(T valueOfUser);
};

template<typename TT> Test<TT>::Test():value(0) {}
template<typename VOOBSHE_DRUGOE_NAZVANIE> Test<VOOBSHE_DRUGOE_NAZVANIE>::Test(VOOBSHE_DRUGOE_NAZVANIE valueOfUser): value(valueOfUser) {}
template<typename T> T Test<T>::getValue() { return value; };
template<typename T> T Test<T>::setValue(T valueOfUser) { value = valueOfUser; }
int main()
{
    Test<int> test(1);
    std::cout << test.getValue();
    return 0;
}
```

Хотелось бы узнать более подробно и поэтапно, как компилятор узнает, каким типом нужно определить `TT`, `VOOBSHE_DRUGOE_NAZVANIE`, `T`, если метод "узнавания" не зависит от имени? Просто когда начинаешь использовать заголовочные файлы и внутри шаблона класса обьявлять метод, а уже где нибудь в `.cpp` определять этот метод, то компилятор не поймет каким типом установить `TT`,`VOOBSHE_DRUGOE_NAZVANIE`, `T`, если класс я создал в каком нибудь другом `.cpp`,   и нужно как нибудь хитрить. Поэтому захотелось заглянуть поглубже.

Comment: Шаблоны обычно следует определять в заголовочном файле. `TT` и `VOOBSHE_DRUGOE_NAZVANIE` это альтернативные идентификаторы для параметра шаблона `T` (использовать разные идентификаторы для одного и того же параметра - плохая идея) и задается явно в строке `Test<int>`

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. У шаблона класса (и шаблонов его методов) есть один типовой параметр. Компилятору достаточно знать это, и знать чему равен соответствующий аргумент. А как он называется в каждом отдельном контексте - значения не имеет.

Answer (score 3):

Предположим где-то в коде у вас содержится следующая инструкция

```
a.setValue(42);
```

При этом компилятор знает, что выражение `a` имеет тип `Test<int>`. Например, ранее `a` было объявлено как ссылка `Test<int> &a` или как объект `Test<int> a`.

Обратите внимание, что вполне возможно, что до этого момента компилятору еще не приходилось искать определения шаблона `Test`. Например, если `а` объявлена как ссылка, то такая ссылка может быть объявлена просто как

```
template <typename> class Test;

void foo(Test<int> &a)
{
  ...
```

То есть для объявления ссылки (или указателя) на `Test<int>` полное определение шаблона `Test` компилятору не нужно вообще. Достаточно лишь "упоминания" (объявления) того факта, что `Test` - это какой-то шаблон класса с каким-то одним типовым параметром.

Но как только компилятор наткнулся на применение оператора `.` к `a` в

```
a.setValue(42);
```

компилятору уже нужно выполнить инстанцирование `Test<int>` и обязательно найти полное определение шаблона `Test`. Из определения `Test<int>` компилятор также выяснит, что такое `setValue`.

Итак, компилятор выполнит поиск определения "главного" шаблона класса `Test<какой-то типовой параметр>`. Найдя это определение, он также выполнит поиск его явных или частичных специализаций (например, `Test<int>`).

В вашем примере компилятор найдет только определение "главного" шаблона

```
template <typename T>
class Test
{
    ...
    T setValue(T valueOfUser);
};
```

То есть компилятор придет к выводу, что тип `a` - это именно данный шаблон с `T == int`.

Либо из главного шаблона, либо из более подходящей специализации (если таковая нашлась) он узнает, что такое `setValue`. В вашем примере это метод шаблонного класса. В этот момент компилятор узнает и типы, и количество параметров метода, и тип его возвращаемого значения.

Затем он выполнит поиск определения шаблона для метода `Test<какой-то типовой параметр>::setValue`. Предположим определение нашлось и выглядит так

```
template <typename VASYA> VASYA Test<VASYA>::setValue(VASYA valueOfUser) 
{ 
  value = valueOfUser; 
}
```

Сопоставив исходное `Test<int>` с `Test<VASYA>` компилятор придет к выводу, что `VASYA == int`. Тот факт, что в определении шаблона класса параметр назывался `T`, а в определении шаблона метода соответствующий параметр называется `VASYA`, совершенно ни на что не влияет и никак в этом процессе не фигурирует.

В дополнение к этому компилятор выполнит поиск явной специализации `Test<int>::setValue`. Если таковой не нашлось, то компилятор воспользуется "главным" шаблоном метода с `VASYA == int` для инстанцирования данного метода. Если найдется явная специализация, то компилятор воспользуется специализацией.

Вот и все.

---

О каком "а уже где нибудь в `.cpp` определять этот метод" вы ведете речь - не ясно. Шаблонные определения должны помещаться в заголовочные файлы. В `.cpp` файл можно помещать только [уже] нешаблонные определения - определения явных специализаций, например.

Comment: Например, у меня есть заголовочный файл "Test.h", в котором есть обьявление шаблонного класса `Test` и внутри которого есть обьявления методов и конструкторов, а вот уже в `Test.cpp` я все это определяю, естественно с  `template`. Подключаю в `Test.cpp` `Test.h` и в `main.cpp` тоже подключаю `Test.h`. Создаю в `main.cpp` например `Test<int> a` и где нибудь ниже пишу `a.getValue()`; получаю ошибку, так как в `Test.cpp` компилятор никак не может определить мои `T`, `TT` @AnT

Comment: это я просто прояснить, согласен, что непонятно написал, а так ответ получен от вас, спасибо. @AnT

Comment: @Kaznachei: Ну так, как вам уже сказали, так делать "нельзя". Определения методов тоже должны находиться в `Test.h`, а `Test.cpp` вам скорее всего не понадобится вообще (если у вас нет явных специализаций). А ошибка, которую вы получаете в вашем варианте, не имеет никакого отношения к `T` и  `TT`. Почему вы решили, что она происходит  потому, что "компилятор никак не может определить мои T, TT" - не знаю.